# Can someone please check my code it won't work, I checked it and i kind find what's wrong. (Processing)

Tags: processing

The code is supposed to make a random shape with four points if I click my mouse. but for some reason, it won't work. can someone please overview my code and tell me what the problem is and how to fix

```
void setup(){
int a = 50;
int b = 50;
int c = 50;
int d = 50;
int e = 50;
int f = 50;
int g = 50;
int h = 50;
int red = 50;
int blue = 50;
int green = 50;
a = random(1,500);
b = random(1,400);
c = random(1,500);
d = random(1,400);
e = random(1,500);
f = random(1,400);
g = random(1,500);
h = random(1,400);
red = random(1,255);
blue = random(1,255);
green = random(1,255);
size(500,400);
}

void drawQuad() {
fill(red,blue,green);
stroke(red,blue,green);
quad(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h);
}

void draw() {
if (mousePressed) {
 drawQuad();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't actually explain anything you tried or what you *think* the problem is. Please do so in the future. Read and memorize [this article](https://medium.com/@gordon_zhu/how-to-be-great-at-asking-questions-e37be04d0603), it'll help you a lot down the line. People tend to not answer your questions if they have to do the work for you.

I took the liberty of running your code locally and I was immediately thrown the following error:

cannot convert from float to int

[image: cannot convert from float to int]

This should indicate to you that you are trying to convert a float value to an int, which is not allowed in Java (the language that Processing is based on), unless you explicitly cast the float to an integer.

The Processing coding environment even highlights where you went wrong:

[image: red squiggly line under the random function]

At this point you should have taken a look at the [documentation of the random function](https://processing.org/reference/random_.html) which says the random function returns a float.

Thus, you were trying to fill an integer value with a float. Again, Java cannot implicitly convert a float to an int, and thus throws an exception.

What you want to do is `int(random(<value>))`, so you convert the float that's returned by the random function to an int. (Note: This does NOT make the original output value an integer, but rounds the outputted float down - `2.0f` becomes `2`, `2.1f` becomes `2`, `2.5f` becomes `2`, and `2.9999999f` becomes `2`)).

Then there's another problem with your code.

You are setting all your values in the `setup()` function, which runs only once. You are then reusing these randomly selected values each time you call `drawQuad()`. If you want them to be random each and every time you click, you need to call the `random()` function inside the `drawQuad()` function.

Comment: Thank you for helping me with this code, I will defiantly try to explain the problem and my code better next time. Also, I am using a site online which doesn't tell me the problem or what is wrong, it just tells me something is wrong. thanks for helping.

Answer (score -1):

This is kind of interesting:

```
float a = 50;
float b = 50;
float c = 50;
float d = 50;
float e = 50;
float f = 50;
float g = 50;
float h = 50;

void setup(){
size(500,400);
}

void drawQuad() {
fill(random(1,255),random(1,255),random(1,255));
stroke(random(1,255),random(1,255),random(1,255));
quad(random(1,500),random(1,400),random(1,500),random(1,400),random(1,500),random(1,400),random(1,500),random(1,400));
}

void draw() {
if (mousePressed) {
 drawQuad();
}
}
```

Comment: Whilst this code does what OP wants, it provides absolutely no explanation.

Comment: Students learn in different ways and likewise teachers teach in different ways.  Some people learn by looking at code examples.  It should be pretty obvious what the problems were, but thanks for your explanation.